# Error when saving to keychain using SecItemAdd

Tags: swift, keychain

I'm getting an error saving an encoded value to keychain at the point of `SecItemAdd`. I'm fairly new to working with Keychain and not sure how to return the error to see what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()


  func initiateLogin(forceReconnect: Bool = false, completion: @escaping (Bool)->Void) {
      Task {
          await loginUser(forceReconnect: forceReconnect, completion: { user in

              if let encoded = try? self.encoder.encode(user) {

                  // MARK: - keychain

                  let attributes: [String: Any] = [
                    kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                    kSecAttrAccount as String: "johnDoe",
                    kSecValueData as String: encoded,
                  ]

                  if SecItemAdd(attributes as CFDictionary, nil) == noErr {
                      print("\(#function)  user saved successfully in keychain")
                  } else {
                      print("\(#function) ⚠️ something went wrong")
                  }

                  self.initClient(withCredentials: user)
                  completion(true)
              }
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify which error you are getting (it should be a return value of `SecItemAdd`), but the most common mistake is this: as [documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/adding_a_password_to_the_keychain):

> The operation might fail, for example, if an item with the given attributes already exists.

In other words: your code will only work *once* for each unique `kSecAttrAccount`.

Instead, you need to check if an item already exists, and if yes, update it (or delete the previous one and create a new one).

How to update the items or delete them is explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/updating_and_deleting_keychain_items).

Side note: it's also a good idea to put keychain management into a separate class (a wrapper), which you can call from anywhere in your code to save / load data from keychain. [Here's](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9240-keychain-services-api-tutorial-for-passwords-in-swift) a good tutorial on how to create such wrapper.